# How to set delayed AWS Lambda call inside other lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-ses

I have a scheduled daemon lambda that is called once a day to analyze data and create needed alert messages for the users of the app for the further sending.
The problem I try to solve is to avoid "sparks" in email sending since if I try to send all the created emails at one moment I will get natural reject from SES. So I plan to store created emails somewhere (SQS, DynamoDB, etc) and then schedule a run of another lambda that will take a portion of emails, call SES.sendEmail(), then if there are still emails to send, schedule another call of itself in a few seconds.
I planned to create CloudWatch event inside lambda and use Cron to schedule lambda call but realized that Cron has 1 minute precision, which is not enough for my purposes. I'm not going to wait inside any lambda (since its just pay for nothing approach), so Lambda.Invoke() is also inappropriate. Are there any other alternatives to recursively schedule call of lambda from itself with conditional delay and seconds precision?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/welcome.html - this is the service you're looking for, in particular the `Wait` state.

Comment: @oakad Yes, exactly, thank you! It can solve the whole task - run email composer function that will put emails to DB, than run "email portion sender" function to get emails from DB and send them. Then state machine can check  from email sender output if there are emails left, then wait and run email sender again if needed. Also all error handling and logging can be done in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a lambda that publishes the emails to sqs, which allows you to set a [delivery delay](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-send-message-with-timer.html), and have another lambda [which is triggered](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-lambda-adds-amazon-simple-queue-service-to-supported-event-sources/) by messages in the queue.

Comment: I've found that AWS Step function is a much better approach than SQS in my case since SQS doesn't solve the problem of restarting "email portion sender" lambda

Comment: @ArseniiFomin Yes, that is better for regions that support Step Functions.